# How to add View to Frame Layout Android

Tags: android, view, camera, android-framelayout

I'm trying to get a simple camera app up.
I have used the sample CameraPreview code provided by Google.
And even the code below is taken from the documentation on the android developers site.
But there's a problem with adding the view mPreview.
It fails in the following 2 conditions-it says application stopped unexpectedely, please try again-there are no logs either:

i) preview.addView(mPreview) and

ii)setContentView(mPreview)

I tried the option ii) just to eliminate possibility of there being something wrong with the CameraPreview code.

But option i) does not work even for the Capture Button.
So I was wondering what is wrong with addView.

I did go through a lot of forums, haven't seen this problem. I also considered using LayoutInflater but I don't see how it applies here.

```
public class CameraTrialActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 private Camera mCamera;    
 private CameraPreview mPreview; 
 private final String TAG = "Camera Preview";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create an instance of Camera       
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();        
        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.      
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);      
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);       
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        Button captureButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        //preview.addView(captureButton);
        //captureButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //setContentView(mPreview);
    }
}
```

//XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
     android:orientation="horizontal"    
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
>  
 <FrameLayout    
     android:id="@+id/camera_preview"    
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
     android:layout_weight="1"    />  

    <Button    
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"    
        android:text="Capture"    
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is `CameraPreview` the class provided by Google?  The one that extends `Activity`?

Comment: It is actually the Preview class which does not extend Activity but SurfaceView.